# For positive self adjoint $T$, show $|\langle Tx,y\rangle|^2 \le \langle Tx,x\rangle \langle Ty,y\rangle$

Tags: inequality, inner-products, adjoint-operators

As in title, $T$ is a positive self adjoint, bounded linear operator on a Hilbert Space $X$ and I'd like to show

$$|\langle Tx,y\rangle|^2 \le \langle Tx,x\rangle \langle Ty,y\rangle$$

Self adjoint means we have $|\langle Tx,y\rangle|=|\langle x,Ty\rangle|=|\langle Ty, x\rangle|$. So by CS-inequality we have

$$
|\langle Tx,y \rangle|^2\le \|Tx\|\cdot \|Ty\| \cdot \|x\| \cdot \|y\|
$$

But I'm not sure if this is a right approach - is it true that for positive operators $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\|Tx\|\cdot \|x\|$? if so, I'm done but I'm rather skeptical about that - I know that equality holds iff $Tx$ is a scalar multiple of $x$, but I don't see any reason why that might be the case for every $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive operator simply means that $\langle v,Tv\rangle\geq 0$, $\forall v$. For instance, given $t\in \mathbb{R}$, you have
$$
0\leq \langle y-tx,T(y-tx)\rangle = \langle y,Ty\rangle - 2t\langle x,Ty\rangle + t^2\langle x,Tx\rangle
$$
and therefore...

Comment: You'd get $\langle y,Ty\rangle-2t \Re \langle y,Tx\rangle +t^2 \langle x,Tx \rangle$ on RHS in complex space I guess? But I fail to see how this is relevant to inequality to be proved - can you give a bit more hints?

Comment: That would be a second degree polynomial in $t$, which would always be positive... How can a second degree polynomial be always positive? ;-)

Comment: It's basically the same idea behind the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Ohh, I get it, so for no roots you need $b^2 -4ac <0$ where $b$ and $a,c$ are those coefficients. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to show that 
$$\langle x,y \rangle_T:= \langle Tx,y\rangle$$
is an inner product on the Hilbert space. I leave it to you to verify this. Once you have shown that, by Cauchy Schwarz
$$|\langle x,y \rangle_T|^2 \leq \langle x,x \rangle_T\langle y,y \rangle_T$$