# For positive T, show ⟨Tx,y⟩≤⟨Tx,x⟩⟨Ty,y⟩

Tags: operator-theory, inner-products

I saw an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826633/for-positive-self-adjoint-t-show-langle-tx-y-rangle2-le-langle-tx-x-ra) for when T is positive AND self adjoint. However, I have to show that the inequality ⟨Tx,y⟩≤⟨Tx,x⟩⟨Ty,y⟩ holds when T is positive.

I assume I'll have to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I don't think I'm doing this right:

⟨Tx,y⟩≤||Tx||⋅||y||=||T||⋅||x||⋅||y||

Any hints towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's not true in the form you stated, consider $T$ as the identity. Then $\langle x,x\rangle \not\le \langle x,x\rangle^2$ in general. Also, note that positive maps are usually self-adjoint by definition.

Comment: Thanks @mechanodroid I forgot the definition of positive gives that it is also self-adjoint. As for the other piece, I agree with you and user284331 but need to confirm with my teacher.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun I'll look those over before I post another question.

Answer (score 2):

So let $[x,y]=\left<Tx,y\right>$, we have $[x,x]=\left<Tx,x\right>\geq 0$ and $[y,x]=\left<Ty,x\right>=\left<y,Tx\right>=\overline{\left<Tx,y\right>}=\overline{[x,y]}$, linearity and scalar conjugate are easy to check. Now use Cauchy-Schwarz.

It is $|\left<Tx,y\right>|^{2}\leq\left<Tx,x\right>\left<Ty,y\right>$.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correctly, you are suggesting I define <Tx,y> by another inner product [x,y] and show that [x,y] is positive and self-adjoint. Then we can use CS to state: <Tx,y> = <x,y> ≤ ||x|| ⋅ ||y|| = <Tx,x> ⋅ <Ty,y>

Comment: Note that $[x,x]=\|x\|_{[\cdot,\cdot]}^{2}$, so there is a square.

Comment: Ah ok, I see that now. The only part that is still strange to me then is that I was asked to prove ⟨Tx,y⟩≤⟨Tx,x⟩⟨Ty,y⟩. I did leave out that this is in a Hilbert space, but I don't know if that would change anything.

Comment: So that is not correct, as @mechanodroid has indicated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to confirm if the question was written incorrectly. I definitely understand how we show this inequality now.